# Eloquent relationship depending on a different parent column being null

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

Using Laravel 10, I have two Eloquent models: "RFP" and "Company".

"RFP" has two different relationships to "Company":

1. Either `RFP.client_company_id = Company.id` OR
2. `RFP.company_id = Company.id AND RFP.client_company_id IS NULL`.

Establishing a relationship the first way is easy:

```php
public function companyPurchasingThroughAgency(): BelongsTo
{
  return $this->belongsTo(Company::class, 'client_company_id');
}
```

I **cannot figure out the second way**, however. It seems like it should be something like:

```php
public function companyPurchasingDirectly(): BelongsTo
{
  return $this->belongsTo(Company::class, 'company_id')
    ->whereNull('client_company_id'); // This is wrong, because the condition is on `Company` not `RFP`
}
```

Is it possible to have a relationship depend on a parent column condition? I can easily return just the `company_id` relationship and then have the caller remove records where `client_company_id` is null, but that doesn't accurately model the relationship, since it `client_company_id` *must be* null for `company_id` to represent a direct purchase for this company.

I'd be OK having the relationship miss the "client_company_id IS NULL" constraint if there was an easy way to put that into a reusable method and only call that.

Comment: Delete whereNull... and replace with `whereHas('rfps', function ($query) {
            $query->where('client_company_id', '=', null);
        })`

Comment: Thanks! In this case you're expecting "rfps" to be a relationship on `Company` based on `company_id`, right? This will accomplish the goal but it adds a dependent subquery that has needless performance implications.

Comment: Remove the where null. Use in your logic: give me RFP with relations (companyPurchasingDirectly) where does not have relation (companyPurchasingThroughAgency) https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-absence

Comment: @marius-ciclistu Thank you! I think that feels elegant to me. And there's no way to have that relationship automatically exclude the other relationship then, is that right? To represent the Business Logic those are the two types, so it'd be nice to call "companyPurchasingDirectly" and have that automatically know to exclude "companyPurchashingThroughAgency", if that makes sense.

Comment: you must chain the 2 conditions one on each relations. You can't do both conditions in one.